# HTML and XSLT transformation

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xhtml

I have simple question,

Can I use XSLT to transform HTML to other HTML.

If it's possible, how i should do this?

Answer (score 2):

If your input HTML is well-formed XML, then you can use XSLT to transform your input HTML in any text format.

Comment: If your input is not well formed XML then you are going to struggle to use XSLT to do *anything* with it! :-)

Answer (score 2):

## [TSaxon](http://vrici.lojban.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/tsaxon/)

> TSaxon is a minor but convenient repackaging of Michael Kay's Saxon
>   6.5.5 XSLT 1.0 processor to make it understand HTML as well as XML
>   input. TSaxon's version of saxon.jar is a drop-in replacement for
>   Saxon's. The only changed source code is
>   [`com.icl.saxon.StyleSheet.java`](http://vrici.lojban.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/tsaxon/StyleSheet.java)

You can invoke it like this:

```
java -jar saxon.jar -H html-doc style-doc
```

> All other options are as in Saxon.
>
> **If you prefer using a later version of Saxon that supports XSLT 2.0
>   and XQuery, you can use the standard Saxon option:**

```
-x org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser
```

> making sure that TagSoup is on your Java classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You could try TagSoup (http://vrici.lojban.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/][1](http://vrici.lojban.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/)) for messy HTML and plug your XSLT into that.